# ReactJS: onClick function from props not working for li element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, onclick

Hello I am passing the function onLocationSelect to a component called 'DropDownSearch' via props, however whenever I try to click the li elements, onLocationSelect does not get called...

Would the divs in the li element be in sense "covering" the li element from being clicked? or is there a different error at play here?

```
// CreateGame.js

onLocationSelect(location) {
    this.setState({ selectedLocation: location });
    console.log(location);
}

render() {
    return (
        <h3>Location</h3>
        <div className="create-game-inputs">
            <DropDownSearch
                fetchYelpBusinesses={yelpSearch}
                location={this.state.location}
                yelpSearchResults={this.props.yelpSearchResults}
                onLocationSelect={this.onLocationSelect}
            />
        </div>
    )

}



// DropDownSearch.js

renderSearchResults(results) {
    return results.map(item => {
        return (
            <li
                name="dds-item"
                key={item.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.onLocationSelect(item)}
            >
                <div className="dds-item-img">
                    <img src={item.image_url} alt={item.name} />
                </div>
                <div className="dds-item-info">
                    <div className="dds-item-name">{item.name}</div>
                    <div className="dds-item-address">
                        {item.location.address1},{item.location.city},
                        {item.location.state}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="dds-search-wrapper">
            <input
                name="searchTerm"
                type="search"
                value={this.state.searchTerm}
                onChange={this.onSearchChange}
                onFocus={this.onSearchFocus}
                onBlur={this.onSearchBlur}
                autoComplete="off"
            />

            {this.props.yelpSearchResults &&
                this.state.listOpen && (
                    <ul className="dds-list">
                        {this.renderSearchResults(
                            this.props.yelpSearchResults
                        )}
                    </ul>
                )}

            <input
                name="location"
                type="search"
                value={this.state.location}
                onChange={this.onLocationChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens. Describe that in detail Can you also share the render of your child and parent component code as well?

Comment: Hey there, I have just edited my question to include more code and  info. What I meant by 'nothing happens' was that the function passed down from this.props from the parent component did not get called when I click on a <li> element rendered in the child component.

Comment: Are you doing binding of this.onLocationSelect function in your parent component?

Comment: Yes I am doing the binding of `this.onLocationSelect` in the parent component's constructor. I think what I have posted already is all that relevant to the problem/code.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Except this  location={this.state.selectedLocation} You need to change location={this.state.location} this to location={this.state.selectedLocation} while passing to DropDownSearch component

Comment: `location` prop is used for a different function. It is not used by `this.onLocationSelect`. My problem is that the `console.log(location)` in the `onLocationSelect` is not called on click.

Comment: Also this has to be enclosed between div or span <h3>Location</h3>
        <div className="create-game-inputs">
            <DropDownSearch
                fetchYelpBusinesses={yelpSearch}
                location={this.state.location}
                yelpSearchResults={this.props.yelpSearchResults}
                onLocationSelect={this.onLocationSelect}
            />
        </div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179508/discussion-between-think-twice-and-kayq).